# Problems matching a long value in Rest Assured json body

Tags: testing, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I have the following response:

```
[
    {
        "id": 53,
        "fileUri": "abc",
        "filename": "abc.jpg",
        "fileSizeBytes": 578466,
        "createdDate": "2018-10-15",
        "updatedDate": "2018-10-15"
    },
    {
        "id": 54,
        "fileUri": "xyz",
        "filename": "xyz.pdf",
        "fileSizeBytes": 88170994,
        "createdDate": "2018-10-15",
        "updatedDate": "2018-10-15"
    }
]
```

and I am trying to match the `id` value to the object in JUnit like so:

```
RestAssured.given() //
                .expect() //
                .statusCode(HttpStatus.SC_OK) //
                .when() //
                .get(String.format("%s/%s/file", URL_BASE, id)) //
                .then() //
                .log().all() //
                .body("", hasSize(2)) //
                .body("id", hasItems(file1.getId(), file2.getId()));
```

But when the match occurs it tries to match an `int` to a `long`.  Instead I get this output:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
JSON path id doesn't match.
Expected: (a collection containing <53L> and a collection containing <54L>)
  Actual: [53, 54]
```

How does one tell Rest Assured that the value is indeed a long even though it might be short enough to fit in an int?  I can cast the file's `id` to an `int` and it works, but that seems sloppy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when converting from json to java type, int type selected,
one solution is to compare int values.
instead of

```
.body("id", hasItems(file1.getId(), file2.getId()));
```

use

```
.body("id", hasItems(new Long(file1.getId()).intValue(), new Long(file2.getId()).intValue()));
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55863912/1909798) answer, the `Integer` type is preferred by RestAssured during the deserialization. However, if you really need to assure the data type, you can use a number greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, to force the deserialization to use `Long`.

So, in your example:

```json
[
    {
        "id": Integer.MAX_VALUE + 53,
        "fileUri": "abc",
        "filename": "abc.jpg",
        "fileSizeBytes": 578466,
        "createdDate": "2018-10-15",
        "updatedDate": "2018-10-15"
    },
    {
        "id": Integer.MAX_VALUE + 54,
        "fileUri": "xyz",
        "filename": "xyz.pdf",
        "fileSizeBytes": 88170994,
        "createdDate": "2018-10-15",
        "updatedDate": "2018-10-15"
    }
]
```

And the assertion:

```java
RestAssured.given()
                .expect()
                .statusCode(HttpStatus.SC_OK)
                .when()
                .get(String.format("%s/%s/file", URL_BASE, id))
                .then()
                .body("id", hasItems(
                    Integer.MAX_VALUE + file1.getId(), 
                    Integer.MAX_VALUE + file2.getId()));
```